# StackExchange.Redis Get function throws a TimeoutException

Tags: c#, caching, redis, connection, stackexchange.redis

I'm using `StackExchange.Redis` with C# and the `StackExchangeRedisCacheClient.Get` function throws the following exception.

> `myCacheClient.Database.StringGet(txtKey.Text)`
>
> `'myCacheClient.Database.StringGet(txtKey.Text)'` threw an exception of type `'System.TimeoutException'`   `StackExchange.Redis.RedisValue` `{System.TimeoutException}`
>
> Message
>
> "Timeout performing GET hi, inst: 12, mgr: ExecuteSelect, err: never, queue: 2, qu: 2, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 1, in: 0, ar: 0, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=4,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=3,Free=4092,Min=4,Max=4095), clientName: ATT-AP-R8-F8WZD"  string

Following is the method that I use to retrieve values from the Redis Database.

```
 protected void btnGetValue_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var serializer = new NewtonsoftSerializer();
        var myCacheClient = new StackExchangeRedisCacheClient(serializer);

        var value = myCacheClient.Get<string>(txtKey.Text);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

All the other functions such as Add, GetInfo & FlushDb are working fine.

Comment: What is `StackExchangeRedisCacheClient`? because: that isn't raw `StackExchange.Redis`; how big is the payload that you are fetching here? (`debug object {key}` in `redis-cli` is a fair way of estimating this; look at the `serializedlength:{...}` field)

Comment: I used StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Newtonsoft package as client (https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Newtonsoft/1.1.10).

I tried raw StackExchange.Redis as well (https://www.nuget.org/packages/StackExchange.Redis/1.0.481) but it throws the same error when fetching.
The payload was only a string with 3 characters (key: foo, value: bar) :)

Comment: That's odd; how does `get foo` behave in `redis-cli`? fast? or slow? also: is it possible that other redis clients on the same node are blocking you? for example, an unrelated app calling `keys {something}` ? (`slowlog get` can be helpful here); likewise, is it possible that this relates to persistence / replication? (the server log can help identify this)

Comment: redis-cli is working fast and fine. Can you check if I'm missing something in the configurations?

<redisCacheClient allowAdmin="true" ssl="false" connectTimeout="5000" database="0">
<hosts>
<add host="127.0.0.1" cachePort="6379" />
</hosts>
</redisCacheClient>

Comment: Ah! I see; for some reason your data is queued unsent (`qu: 2`), with no writer (`wr: 0`).  I have *never* seen   that (at least, not in the production builds for the last ... forever), so frankly: I would have to investigate. This is almost certainly either a bug, or a problem in the initial handshake. I will have to look.

Comment: Thanks for you effort. :)

Comment: I'm having similar timeout issues too.  Looking forward to Marc's findings.

Comment: @MarcGravell We're getting the same exception with `qu: 2` and `wr: 0` (`Timeout performing EXEC, inst: 1, mgr: ExecuteSelect, err: never, queue: 2, qu: 2, qs: 0, qc: 0, wr: 0, wq: 0, in: 0, ar: 0, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=1,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=2,Free=32765,Min=1,Max=32767), clientName: xxx`. It's happening sparsely (since tracking this problem, it's happened on Dec 13, 15 and today the 20th). We're using an external service to monitor our Redis instances and we don't see anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Continued: The MVC 5 app using SE.Redis runs without any problems but then we'll randomly see this exception and subsequent `No connection is available to service this operation` exceptions for ~1 second. I'd be glad to provide any information that can help solve this problem.