# StackExchange.Redis.RedisTimeoutException: Timeout exception response

Tags: asp.net-core, redis, stackexchange.redis

Our system uses Redis to save some data. Sometimes, on my application's insights I get a timeout exception like this:

```
Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=0KiB, 20640ms
elapsed, timeout is 20000ms), command=GET, active: GET
9ba45b00-52a6-41da-9acb-621665862a3b:UmsUserData, next: GET
0e730553-b6f5-4882-8c96-b853d549e385:UmsUserData, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs:
3, aw: False, rs: ComputeResult, ws: Idle, in: 1044, serverEndpoint:
Unspecified/azlink012.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, mgr: 9 of
10 available, clientName: RD0050F2931DEA, IOCP:
(Busy=1,Free=999,Min=100,Max=1000), WORKER:
(Busy=26,Free=32741,Min=100,Max=32767), v: 2.0.601.3402 (Please take a
look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause
timeouts:
https://stackexchange.github.io/StackExchange.Redis/Timeouts)
```

I have investigated some parameters like `IOCP(1<100)` and `WORKER(26<100)` and they are normal. What is the problem here?

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57661799/10607772) question?

Comment: Yes, I see `WORKER: (Busy=10,Free=32757,Min=2,Max=32767)` busy(10) > Min(2). But in my case, they are normal. There may be another cause that the message doesn't mention (some thing like network CPU)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my problem on GitHub.

> if you are working with Redis, you should design your application such
> that it can handle connection blips. There are number of reasons due
> to which it can happen like failover, Redis patching etc.

https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis/issues/1378